# I wanna fetch posts from all the users in firebase react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I wanna fetch posts from all the users in firebase.

Here is the fetching code

```js
const fetchPosts = async () => {
    try {
      const list = [];

      await db
        .collection(`posts/*/userPosts`) // This is the line I want help with...

        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          // console.log('Total Posts: ', querySnapshot.size);

          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const { userId, post, postImg, likes, comments } = doc.data();
            list.push({
              id: doc.id,
              userId,
              userName: "Test Name",
              userImg:
                "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-b0PKyNuQv5s/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuuclxAM4M1SCBGAO7Rp-QP6zgBEUkOQ/s96-c/photo.jpg",

              post,
              postImg,
              liked: false,
              likes,
              comments,
            });
          });
        });

      setPosts(list);

      if (loading) {
        setLoading(false);
      }

      console.log("Posts: ", posts);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);
```

And my firebase cloud firestore collection looks in the image below the msg.

And this path is something like this: `/posts/UserUID/userPosts/PostUID`

The thing is that if an user adds a post it just saves like this `/posts/UserUID/userPosts/PostUID`.

So I wanna do is that to just fetch posts from all the users and render them.
Like `` await db.collection(`posts/UserUID/userPosts`) // And there is more but not required for now ``

[image: This is the link to the image:]

Tools:
JavaScript,
Expo,
React Native,
Firebase,
Cloud firestore

Answer (score 0):

use collectionGroups.

Replace

```
await db.collection(`posts/*/userPosts`)
```

with

```
await db.collectionGroup(`userPosts`)
```